# jquery carousel Control function

Tags: jquery

i have [this plugin](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel) and it use different way to access, i spend two couples of hours trying to write a code to go to a specific item (index 5 for example), i have this code

```
var carouselNavigation = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();
```

for

```
    <div class="connected-carousels">


        <div class="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="prev prev-navigation">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a href="#" class="next next-navigation">&rsaquo;</a>
            <div class="carousel carousel-navigation">
                <ul>
                    {foreach $objects as $object}
                        <li><img src="{get_photo details=$object size='xl'}" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now i want to go to index 5 directly by one function such as

```
carouselNavigation.goindex(5);
```

i'm tried

```
carouselNavigation.jcarousel().jcarouselControl({
        target: carouselNavigation.jcarousel('items').eq(5)
});
```

and not worked, then tried

```
carouselNavigation.jcarouselControl({
        target: carouselNavigation.jcarousel('items').eq(5)
});
```

not worked,then

```
jcarouselControl({
        target: carouselNavigation.jcarousel('items').eq(5)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As jcarousel is a method on a jquery element, It seems you could be done by something like :

```
$('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel('items').eq(5);
```

I hope it may help

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/p7bybqyp/

use [scroll](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#scroll) metod:

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel('scroll', 5);
```